# Log out from restricted area without triggering security settings

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I have a section that requires login and a certain role ("higher than 19"). Whenever I logout from it, I get

```
Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

Reason for this are my security settings:

```
".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('data').child('role').val() > 19",
```

My logout function:

```
// Sign out functionality
App.controller('SignOutCtrl', function($scope, $state, Auth) {

    $scope.logout = function() {

        // Go to landing page
        $state.go('home');

        // Log user out
        Auth.$unauth();

    };
});


App.factory('Auth', ['$firebaseAuth', function($firebaseAuth) {

    var firebase = new Firebase('https://mysite.firebaseio.com/');

    return $firebaseAuth(firebase);

}]);
```

The $state 'home' doesn't have any reading restrictions, looks like the log out actually happens before I'm being redirected to the 'home'-$state, which triggers the security restrictions.

I guess I'm struggling to understand the very basic concept of how to log out from a restricted site without triggering the security setting, can anyone please explain me how to do that properly?

Comment: The security restriction is triggered by a listener. So most likely you've created a $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, or established a .on() listener. Since you haven't included the relevant code here it's hard to guess. But essentially, you want to call $destroy() or off() respectively before doing unauth. Or just ignore the benign error.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest unauthenticating when the logout page is loaded instead of before leaving the restricted page.

Comment: So you mean I should create a separate logout page, like page with logout-button > click > logout-page that triggers unauthentication?

Comment: A separate logout page or just pass a query parameter to the landing page that indicates it should log out the user who arrives there before displaying the results (so the first state that's displayed is the state corresponding to a user who is not logged in).